# Derived Column Functionality error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, derived

I have 2 new columns from Derived Column functionality and I have to merge them both into one Column and feed it to the destination Table.

Derived column 1:

```
ABC
BBC
CBC
```

Derived Column 2:

```
HPC
DRT
RTY
```

Derived Column 3 should be

```
ABC
BBC
CBC
HPC
DRT
RTY
```

Comment: And your question is ????

Comment: how should we do that thing ie adding 2 columns into one column

Comment: where are you trying to add two column together ?? what are their data types ?? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have 2 columns created using derived columns I want both the columns to be made into one column both the columns are string type

Comment: SELECT Column1 + ' ' + Column2 FROM TableName        .Should work fine if they both are same datatypes

Comment: I have edited the question please check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `UNION ALL Transformation` AND Then `Derived Column` SSIS will and map the columns. Union ALL with Combine the two column and Derived Column will put the combined columns in One Derived Column.

[image]

something like this..

Comment: I asked this in SSIS.

Comment: Its not mentioned anywhere in your question that you are trying to do this in SSIS, a TIP for next time if you have a question, Provide as much as information possible about your questions, Show what you have tried so far and if possible some Sample Data that what you have in your tables and What you want to do the desired Result set :) And most importantly Use the right Tags with your Question :)

Comment: can you once explain the answer you provided ?

Comment: I believe you have Two Derived Columns on you Data flow You need to Add a UNION ALL Transformation task onto your dataflow Map the columns then add another Derived Column.